# How to use 'DataLoader(dataset=Dataset(train_data, train_label))' in pytorch while I haven't input the whole 'train_data'?

Tags: python, out-of-memory, pytorch, virtual-memory

How can I use virtual memory in pytorch coding? I have a large of input data but can not input all of the into memory once a time, whereas I want to shuffle the whole database in DataLoader. Or if there is any other method to meet this question?

I've got a memory error when I tried to input the whole 'train_data' into memory. It's too large.

train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=Dataset(train_data, train_label), batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

I expect to use the whole 'train_data' directly so that I can use DataLoader to simplify the program of training, but I got a memory error.